# Changing Fragments on button Click

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I want to change fragments depending on button click. (I have made two fragment classes called fragmentLeft and fragmentMiddle)

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
Fragment fr;
    public void selectFrag(View view) {


         if(view == findViewById(R.id.bigbutton_left)) {
             fr = new fragmentLeft();



         }else {
             fr = new fragmentMiddle();

         }

         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

         if (fm != null) {
             // Perform the FragmentTransaction to load in the list tab content.
             // Using FragmentTransaction#replace will destroy any Fragments
             // currently inside R.id.fragment_content and add the new Fragment
             // in its place.
             FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
             ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
             ft.commit();
         }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);


        return true;
    }

}
```

This is fragmentLeft.java

```
public class fragmentLeft extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       //Inflate the layout for this fragment

      return inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.fragmentleft, container, false);
   }
}
```

the same is for fragmenttwo with the exception of the layout id passed to infater.inflate()

I have made two layout files two, with the correct names as well .
This is the definition of my fragment from my activity_main.xml

But I am unable to get the buttons to do anything. No transactions take place, and I am stuck with the first fragment.

After a bit of googling , I came to know that its not recommended that you use fragment in the layout, but some other type of layout, but I saw this example code http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/
that seems to work just fine.

what is the problem ?

**::EDIT::**
**There is something really weird going on. 
If I use this layout xml file  for main Activity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment No.1"
        android:onClick="selectFrag" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="selectFrag"
         android:text="Fragment No.2" /> 

   <fragment
        android:name="com.mainpackage.FragmentOne"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The fragments change and behave as they are expected to.
But if I use this layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bigbutton_middle"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bigbutton_middle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bigbutton_middle"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbutton_right" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bigbutton_left"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bigbutton_middle"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bigbutton_middle"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bigbutton_middle"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbutton_left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bigbutton_middle"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="187dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbutton_middle" />
      <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:name="com.mainpackage.FragmentOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bigbutton_right" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**The fragments dont seem to change,i.e. the buttons seem to be dead.**

What could be the problem ?

I am using Eclipse Juno

Comment: Well, the code you posted doesn't have any reference to Button's `OnClickListeners`. I assume you have some, don't you?

Comment: I dont , I expect the selectFrag to do the job for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting a reference of the `Buttons` you are clicking in order for the `FragmentTransaction` to take place. You need to set `OnClickListeners` on the `Buttons` so they can execute relevant code.

One reason why the second layout doesn't display is because you are referencing an inexistant id:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
android:name="com.mainpackage.FragmentOne"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/bigbutton_right" />
```

I do not see a `View` with an id of `bigButton_right` on that xml.

Another reason why the first xml works and the second doesn't is because you are not setting an `onClick:` property to any `Button` on the second xml.

Comment: but NONE of the buttons work. 
the fragments doesnt swtich. 
even if i place the code for switching fragments in my onCreate(), it doesnt replace the fragments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54128/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-emmanuel).